# using CKEditor with Django and an inlineformset_factory with empty_form

Tags: django

When I render the empty form it is not attaching any media to it. i.e. the CKEditor is not displayed. The element looks like it is missing the css/js - it's like it doesn't get set up properly.

Note : the other sections are displayed correctly.

Where to start? Problem with Django's Empty Form method? Problem with CKEditor? Me :)

```
  <div class="container"> 
        <button type ="button" class="btn-info btn-lg" id="add_section">Add Section</button>
        {{form.media }}
        {{form|crispy }}
        {{sections.media}}
       
        <div> 
            
            {{sections.empty_form}}    
        </div>
 
     
        <div id = 'section_management'> {{ sections.management_form }} </div>
        {% for section in sections %}
            {{ section|crispy }}
          
        {% endfor %}

      

        <button class="btn btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
        <a href="{{ view.get_success_url }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
       
    </div>
```

Here's my Forms

```
  class SectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = RichTextFormField()
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ('content',)

    empty_permitted=True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         print('section form called')
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title','category','span')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_superuser = kwargs.pop('is_superuser', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.is_superuser == False:
            self.fields.pop("span")
```

view code

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'articles/ArticleUpdate.html'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    model = Article
    SectionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Article, Section, form=SectionForm, extra=0, can_delete=False, fields=('content',))
    #if i always pass back at least 1 extra section form, I can grab the html for it in Jquery */
    #if i do not pass back extra=0 how would i get the html in jquery for the extra form?
    def test_func(self):
        article = self.get_object()
        
        if self.request.user == article.author or self.request.user.is_superuser :
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('get context data called update view')
        
        '''
            section_form
        '''
        
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['sections'] = self.SectionFormSet(self.request.POST,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['sections'] = self.SectionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def get_section_form(self):  #we know we can access this in the template
        return SectionForm()

    def save_sections(self):
        print('save sections called update view')
        try:
            context = self.get_context_data()
            section_form = context['sections']
            if section_form.is_valid():
               # section_form.instance = self.object  #if im passing instance in the factory, do I need it here to?
                section_form.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to save section: ' + str(e))


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form valid called update view')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form) #save article form 
        self.save_sections()
        return response

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I've done so far to overcome this problem is by accessing the form directly from the template, bypassing the inlineFormSet to get an empty form....(hope that makes sense).

I go directly to the view :

```
   {{view.get_section_form}}
```

with this method in the view

```
    def get_section_form(self):  #we know we can access this in the template
        return SectionForm()
```

I have subsequently found out I can do this in the template as well :

```
  {{sections.media}}        
  {{sections.form}}
```

The above also passes an empty form - with the media filled in- as long as you pass the model form into the factory to start of with.

These are work-arounds for me currently, but would appreciate a proper answer as to why empty_form doesn't work properly.

My further investigation into this was basically comparing what is returned via accessing the formset to return an empty form, or using the modelForm directly.

Django docs :

```
  empty_form¶
BaseFormSet provides an additional attribute empty_form which returns a form instance with a prefix of __prefix__ for easier use in dynamic forms with JavaScript.
```

If you replace prefix on the generated html -- everything works. No idea why. You can replace it with anything, i.e. **prefix1**

at which point CKEditor starts to display the formset correctly.